# Assistance with the Open-Closed Principle

Tags: design-patterns, open-closed-principle

I was assigned a homework project to figure out why a code snippet does not fit the Open-Closed principle, but I'm having trouble figuring it out. I'm only here asking for someone to set me on the correct path, not to get my homework done for me. If anyone can help me out by telling me what I'm looking for in this code, that would be much appreciated.

```
public class MyQueue<T> extends ArrayList<T> implements Queue<T> {
    int front = 0;
    int back = 0;
    void put(T e) {
        add(back++, e);
    }
    T get() {
        return get(front++);
    }
    // ... other methods from Queue interface
}
```

Comment: Not sure exactly which open/closed principle you mean. Could it be that the underlying list manipulation methods are still available and could violate queue semantics?

Comment: It is specified, at least in the book, by Open for Extension but Closed for Modification. If that helps.

Comment: OP is referring to the 'O' in SOLID

Comment: I cannot for the life of me figure out why this particular piece of code violates this principle. If I could figure that out, modifying the code to fix the issue would be simple.

Comment: Ask yourself how you would you extend this class.

Comment: I've been asking myself that for about 2 hours now. I'm just not getting it.

Comment: In java (this *is* java as far as I can tell), are a Grand Parent's members implicitly overridable by a Child class?

Comment: Would you have to change code to extend it?

Comment: Well, the obvious answer for that is yes, due to the fact that I was told that the code is not OCP compliant. However, personally, I do not see what I would need to change in order to extend this code, nor why I would want to extend it in the first place.

Comment: Don't over think it -- there is no way to add functionality to this class without changing it -- therefore it is not open to extension.

Comment: Alright, so I need to make the class somehow extendable, in that it will no longer need to be modified in order to be extended?

Comment: That's the direction I'd run in.

Comment: Would make the class more like a wrapper be a good decision in this case? IE: adding an ArrayList within the class itself, sort of like what I believe is called the Decorator Pattern?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65919/discussion-between-ranma344-and-dbugger).

Answer (score 0):

Please note the "open closed" principal isn't exact science - it requires human guesswork as to "what people might want to extend". If I create an application that draws a rainbow - would you expect hooks to change color shades? Image size? Or would you expect me to go further and allow hooks to change the image altogether - say to an elephant? Go even further and allow animation... ?

So I can't be a 100% sure what extensions you instructors expects. But it springs to mind that inheritance from ArrayList isn't very nice, don't you think? It violates other principals such as encapsulation, but to the subject at hand - what if I wanted to "plug in" my own List, say one that is backed up by a file? Or one that is replicated on several machines?

You can use your imagination to consider other possible extensions. But that really depends on the level and emphasis of your course. E.g. are you expected to be able to write a Queue that is flexible enough to support a priority queue?